# MySQL INSERT not inserting

Tags: insert, pdo

Here's my code for making an entry into the MySQL db using PDO.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO dictionary (entry, meaning) VALUES (:entry,:meaning)";
$prep=$db->prepare($sql);
$prep->bindParam(':entry',$entry);
$prep->bindParam(':meaning',$meaning);
try{
    $result=$prep->execute(); 
   }
catch(PDOException $e) 
   {
    echo $e->getMessage(); 
   }
```

But it's not inserting anything on the db. What could be the problem?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to bind the parameters together?

Comment: i think not nnecessary. i have been binding them separately and everything used to work

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is useless to ask other people what is wrong with your code. You have to ask your server instead.
So, make sure your PDO throws exceptions on errors. To do so, add this line after connection code

```
$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

Next, move `try` higher in the code

```
try{
    $sql  = "INSERT INTO dictionary (entry, meaning) VALUES (:entry,:meaning)";
    $prep = $db->prepare($sql);
    $prep->bindParam(':entry',$entry);
    $prep->bindParam(':meaning',$meaning);
    $result=$prep->execute(); 
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

and in case of any error you'll be notified of it.